# Uniqueness of the structure sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

Given a ring $A$ and his Spectrum $X=Spec(A)$ seen as a topological space with the Zariski topology, it's possible to build a sheaf on $X$ satisfying the conditions

- $O_X(X)=A$
- $O_X(X_f)=A_f$ where $X_f=X-V(f)$
- $O_{X,p}=A_p$

My question is: do these conditions determine the sheaf uniquely up to isomorphisms of sheaves, or there exists a ring with two non isomorphic sheafs satisfying these properties?

Comment: I think you should at least assume that the restriction maps $A=\mathscr{O}_X(X)\to \mathscr{O}_X(D(f))=A_f$ are the localization maps. This then uniquely determines all the restriction maps for inclusions $D(f)\subseteq D(g)$, and there is a unique sheaf on $X$ with these properties (up to canonical isomorphism, as usual).

Comment: Yes, I agree, but maybe it's true even without that assumption

Comment: I feel like it would be very hard to prove uniqueness without saying something about the restriction maps.

Comment: Yes. Another characterization of the sheaf condition is that it preserves limits (in the opposite category of open sets), hence the unique way of extending to a sheaf is by picking the limit over the basic open sets. Your third condition is, actually, irrelevant.

Comment: About the restriction, it's strictly necessary to be the localization by my previous comment.

Comment: maybe you're mixing something. The definition of limit depends on the restriction maps, so you can't say that the third condition is irrilevant, since you don't know that the limit of $A_f$ is $A_p$. I don't see why the restrictions must be the localizations ones.

Comment: @Exodd A sheaf must preserve limits. This entirely determines $A_p$. About the restrictions, if they're not the localizations, the limit can change.

Comment: Ok, but if you have a sheaf with the first two properties, and no information about the restriction maps, you can't say that the stalks are $A_p$. In this sense, the third condition is relevant

Comment: Ok, I've got your point. In the case the restrictions are the localization, the third assumption is irrelevant. If you are not assuming that the restrictions are the localizations, then I think this may fail. The étale space will be exactly the same set, but the open sets can differ (because the images of the map $A_f \rightarrow A_p$ may differ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample consider a field $k$ and define $A= k[x]_{(x)}$ which is a discrete valuation ring, so $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A) = \{0, (x)\}$ and $\{0\}$ is the only nontrivial open set. Now consider a sheaf $\cal{F}$ on $X$ with $\mathcal{F}(X) = A, \mathcal{ F}(\{0\})= k(x),$ and the restriction map $A=\mathcal{F}(X)\to k(x)=\mathcal{F}(\{0\})$ is given by sending $x$ to $x^2$ i.e. $k[x]_{(x)}\stackrel{\simeq}{\to} k[x^2]_{(x^2)}\to k(x).$ The quotient field of the image of this map is not equal to $\mathcal{F}(\{0\})$ and so this sheaf is not isomorphic to the structure sheaf of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$.

Comment: I don't get how you prove that the sheaf isn't isomorphic to the structure one, but I found another dimonstraction of this fact by myself. The bounty is yours :)